# How do I wait for the physical network interface and network protocol stacks to be up before trying to mount a remote CIFS share?

Tags: networking, mount, fstab

I'm having a problem getting a remote share to mount on boot. 
The mount is attempted before the network interface is ready –
and I've got `_netdev` on the required line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.0.160/raspi /zeus/raspi cifs rw,auto,uid=1001,gid=1002,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,_netdev,vers=3,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials_raspi_01 0 0
```

Here is the part of `dmesg` that explains the issue better than I can:

```
[   46.789814] FS-Cache: Loaded
[   47.278702] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
[   47.534038] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[   47.534076] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[   47.536636] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.160/raspi
[   47.536991] CIFS: VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[   47.537019] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
[   47.628859] sun7i-dwmac 1c50000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   47.628926] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   51.299626] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[   51.346063] NET: Registered protocol family 24
[   51.695526] l2tp_core: L2TP core driver, V2.0
[   51.797914] l2tp_netlink: L2TP netlink interface
[   51.838658] l2tp_ppp: PPPoL2TP kernel driver, V2.0
[   78.924908] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
[  124.605250] perf: interrupt took too long (2531 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79000
[  157.116937] perf: interrupt took too long (3183 > 3163), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62750
[  204.593797] perf: interrupt took too long (4016 > 3978), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49750
[  276.966459] perf: interrupt took too long (5041 > 5020), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 39500
[  395.988260] perf: interrupt took too long (6303 > 6301), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 31500
[  863.282125] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.0.160/raspi
```

At 863.282125 I manually issued the command `mount /zeus/raspi`,
which successfully created the remote fs mount.

I've been trying to sort this one out for more than a month. 
Can anyone help me to get the OS to wait for
the network physical link and IP protocol stack to be fully up
before trying to connect to the remote share using the line in `/etc/fstab`?

```
root@loki:~# uname -a
Linux loki 5.10.60-sunxi #21.08.2 SMP Tue Sep 14 16:28:44 UTC 2021 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
root@loki:~# systemd --version
systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

Armbian 21.08.6 Focal with Linux 5.10.60-sunxi

https://github.com/search?q=armbian

https://www.armbian.com/banana-pi-pro/

Comment: what's the linux distro/version and systemd version?

Comment: I've added the information to the end of the problem description. Should have done that from the start. Thank-you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug.

The option **_netdev** (which you already have) is the one you need - it tells the mount that this is network device which should be mounted after network interface is up.

I would start with looking at the OS itself and the mounting modules - maybe they are too old to know **_netdev** option and could be updated?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the technical know-how. It did work and somewhere along the line stopped working. The OS is a maintained version of Armbian.